# Zonal statistics USFS tree cover by census block

Tags: qgis, raster, r, zonal-statistics, large-datasets

I want average tree cover for every census block. I have a file of census blocks, and I have a USFS tree cover file from [USFS Tree Canopy Cover Datasets](https://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/rastergateway/treecanopycover/) that looks like this:

[image: over]

I'm trying to use zonal statistics but the files are too big- even though my computer is very powerful QGIS only uses <3GB of RAM for some reason.

Is there a way to speed this up?

I tried using R's `exact_extractr` but I got all `NaN`s.

```
rasta = raster('canopy.tif')
poly3 = st_read("cbg.shp")
foliage <- exact_extract(rasta, poly3, 'mean')
```

Comment: In what way are the files "too big"? Do you get errors loading them into R? What's the resolution and size? What's the size of the census blocks compared to the raster cell size? How many census blocks are there? Can you run this for one census block? Can you subdivide into states or counties to make it easier?

Comment: I can't see why you'd get all NaNs with exactextractr (I'm the author). Can you share the specific inputs you're using?

Comment: one of them is the first CONUS zip link at the USFS site I linked to above. The other is a gdb https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1c924a53319a491ab43d5cb1d55d8561

Comment: You're seeing NaNs because the first block groups in the file are from Hawaii, which is not covered by the CONUS raster. The results aren't "all NaN", but R only displays the first 1000 results by default, and there are 219,000 block groups. (3,940 of them are NaN).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the GRASS GIS tool, [v.rast.stats](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.rast.stats.html) to see it is more efficient. In order to get set-up in GRASS with your Location and Mapset, please review the tutorial [here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Quick_wxGUI_tutorial) and associated 'Getting Started docs'. Once inside your GRASS location,you could run the following commands:

```
##import your polygon
v.in.ogr input=cbg.shp output=cbg

##import your raster
r.in.gdal input=canopy.tif output=canopy

##calculate univariate statistics for each polygon, including mean
v.rast.stats map=cbg raster=canopy column_prefix=stat_ method=mean
```

You can also leave the `method` empty to calculate a range of default statistics.

Alternatively, you could try to run the tool from within QGIS, see screenshot below:

[image]
Regarding your second question concerning `extract_exact`, perhaps you need to remove NAs, have you tried:

```
rasta = raster('canopy.tif')
poly3 = st_read("cbg.shp")
foliage <- exact_extract(rasta, poly3, 'mean', na.rm=TRUE)
```

More details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/readme/README.html)

While the approaches outlined above are valid, you may still need to consider tiling (e.g. `gdal_retile.py`) your dataset in order to reduce the associated file size of your raster.

Comment: what is a GRASS location? Is it in QGIS? R?

Comment: a GRASS location is specific  to GRASS-GIS  (see edited answer above). Alternatively run the tool in QGIS if it is easier.

Comment: I tried na.rm = true and I got
```Error in .local(x, y, ...) : 
  exact_extract was called with a named summary operation that does not accept additional arguments ...
In addition: Warning message:
In .local(x, y, ...) : Polygons transformed to raster CRS (EPSG:NA)
```

Comment: And when I use v.rast.stats I get all NA values for the mean...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using regular Zonal Statistics in QGIS, I let it run for four hours but it worked. Other methods just gave me NA as the mean

Comment: If you are running QGIS > 3.14, I'd recommend to have a look at the command line tool `qgis_process`. Thus you can use qgis tools from scripts, e.g. from R.